# Expression Expected and statement error in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, expression

Guys Help me about my error. There are two errors, I just can't figure it out.
The 2 errors are:

1. Expression Expected. = "And" statement on line 4
2. End of statement expected. = "Then" Statement on line 5

Here is my code:

```
Public Class adminlog
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.Username And
            TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.Password Then
            main.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect Username or Password!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
        reg.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: ERROR]

Any suggestions will help.

Comment: use Option Strict https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/4022/option-strict/14043/how-to-switch-it-on and `My.Settings.Default.Username`

Comment: @Slai : What's the difference between `My.Settings.*` and `My.Settings.Default.*`? Is the latter the initial value?

Comment: @VisualVincent seems like I mixed them up a bit with C# where it is `Properties.Settings.Default.Username` instead of `My.Settings.Username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a [**line continuation character**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9sxbw4.aspx). The expression within an `If`-statement is supposed to be in one line, so to break it up into multiple lines you must add VB.NET's line continuation character (which is the underscore, `_`) after `And`:

```
If TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.Username And _
    TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.Password Then
```

Comment: There's a whole bunch of things that allow implicit line continuation like commas, dot operators, And, AndAlso.   See [Statements in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865x40k4(v=vs.100).aspx)  the list changed a little with each version so pick your version at the top

Comment: Thank you Vincent.I Got it ^_^

Comment: @JeckIer Note that if you have this problem your VB version is not new. Newer versions do allow implicit line continuation after `And`. You must be using VS 2008.

Comment: @GSerg : I use VS2010 and if I recall it correctly you have to use explicit line continuation there.

Comment: @VisualVincent Please see the link Plutonix posted. The implicit continuation started in VB 2010 and already included `And` as a continuation point, unless the documentation is wrong. Certainly works after `And` in VB 2012.

Comment: @VisualVincent Ahh i see ...yes i'm using vb 2008 ..I'ts very simple error...By the way Thank you ^_^

Comment: @Jeckler : No problem, though it was GSerg who pointed out the thing about the VS version.

Comment: @JeckIer you might want to install a newer version of Visual Studio (2015 is the current release and 2017 is about to be released). Visual Studio Community Edition (both 2015 and 2017) is free for individuals and small companies.

Comment: @Blackwood do you know the link where can i download it?Thank you

Comment: @JeckIer Here are links for [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) and [Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-2017-rc/). Note that the 2017 version is a Release Candidate (RC) and might be modified before the final release.